# Linux kernel module "Unknown parameter" stops module from loading. How to load module anyway?

Tags: linux, kernel

The following is happening on a Ubuntu 10.04 system I'm working on:

- The kernel is shipped with e1000 driver module version `7.3.21-k5-NAPI`.
- This version of the module is causing problems.
- To fix, the system requires a newer e1000 network driver module, version `8.0.35-NAPI`.
- A (`make && make install`) will compile the module and place it in `/lib/modules/[current kernel version]/kernel/drivers/net/e1000`
- There is no direct physical access to the machine. In other words: this machine should be able to boot on it's own without interaction in most cases.

Problem:

- Version `8.0.35-NAPI` has a parameter (`ignore_64bit_dma`) which isn't available in the module shipped with the kernel.
- When running a `apt-get dist-upgrade` the currently used kernel may be upgraded. If someone forgets to install the newer e1000 module before rebooting, the kernel will attempt to load the module shipped with the kernel. This module doesn't have the `ignore_64bit_dma` parameter. This will cause the driver module not to load -at all-, with the message: `e1000: Unknown parameter 'ignore_64bit_dma'`.

Questions:

- Is it possible to load the e1000 module automatically on boot, dropping the unknown parameter automatically, -only- in case version `7.3.21-k5-NAPI` is loaded?

It would be preferred if solutions are not experimental, and do not require seperate scripts.